# Twitter Profile Upload Error

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, upload, lan

I get several errors when I try to upload a picture on twitter. (Just on Twitter)

I done some research over html and console and got following results:

- On wireless lan: No error | On cable-bounded lan: error

I get these errors:

https://abs.twimg.com/a/1463112091/css/t1/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

https://upload.twitter.com/i/media/upload.json?origin=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

https://twitter.com/i/jot Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: AS such there's no reason why things would be different between wireless and wired networks. Are you sure everything on those networks is working properly (such as DNS servers, connectivity to the servers used etc.

Comment: @swa66 Actually I tested another router. It worked. Now I search through the router settings. Maybe It is a resolve bug.

Comment: @swa66 Google DNS used.